# Clearing out arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I need to clear 2 arrays before i execute a function a 2nd time.

They are initially setup globally as :-

```
NSString *allAnswers[10];
int used[6];
```

What would be needed to clear/reset these before running the function again?

Thanks.

Comment: Clear means what? Do you want to assign `0` to all?

Comment: Are you sure this is C and not Objective-C? There's no such thing as "clearing an array" in C.

Comment: Use `NSNutableArray`, not a "c" array of `NSString` pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through those items, resetting their values to whatever you want.

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    allAnswers[i] = nil;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    used[i] = 0;
```

If using Objective-C, you might want to consider using [`NSMutableArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in the future rather than C-language arrays like these.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop to clear your arrays by `0` or whatever value you want.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     if(i < 6)  
         used[i] = 0;
     allAnswer[i] = 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
memset(allAnswers, 0, sizeof(NSString*)*10);//This statement to clear array of NSString pointers
memset(used, 0, sizeof(int)*6);//This statement to clear array of integers.
```

Alternatively you can run loop to clear each element individually.

Comment: This will not work with the `NSString` array. You're bypassing the Objective-C memory management, and you will leak.

Comment: @rob Ya i checked it, it shows bad access error. Is it due to memory leak? And thanks for correcting :)

Comment: I'm surprised that you got bad access error, but it definitely leaks.